# Filtering Pandas Dataframe according to indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, locate

Consider following dataframe:

`m.transmission`

```
                                         eff    inv-cost    fix-cost  var-cost
Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity

Mid     North    hvac         Elec       0.90   1650000     16500         0
Mid     South    hvac         Elec       0.90   1650000     16500         0
North   Mid      hvac         Elec       0.90   1650000     16500         0
North   South    hvac         Elec       0.85   3000000     30000         0
South   Mid      hvac         Elec       0.90   1650000     16500         0
South   North    hvac         Elec       0.85   3000000     30000         0
```

I would like to filter values according to, if `Site In == 'Mid'` or `Site Out == 'Mid'`

How would I do it? Before saying anything, this is not the desired outcome:

`m.transmission.loc[['Mid']]`

```
Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity 
Mid     North    hvac         Elec
Mid     South    hvac         Elec
```

because it just filters if `Site In == 'Mid'`

Desired output would be (ofc with the columns; such as eff, inv-cost, fix-cost, var-cost):

```
Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity 
Mid     North    hvac         Elec
Mid     South    hvac         Elec
North   Mid      hvac         Elec
South   Mid      hvac         Elec
```

EXTRA

```
(Pdb) m.transmission.columns
Index(['eff', 'inv-cost', 'fix-cost', 'var-cost', 'inst-cap', 'cap-lo',
       'cap-up', 'wacc', 'depreciation'],
      dtype='object')
(Pdb) m.transmission.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['Mid', 'North', 'South'], ['Mid', 'North', 'South'], ['hvac'], ['Elec']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['Site In', 'Site Out', 'Transmission', 'Commodity'])
```

Comment: With your update, it shows, all 4 are part of multiindex, not columns, this isn't a complete dataframe.

Comment: There are columns, with eff, inv-cost, fix-cost, etc... I did not put them in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'columns' are in index.

```
In [217]: df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('Site In') == 'Mid') | 
                 (df.index.get_level_values('Site Out') == 'Mid')]
Out[217]:
                                         v
Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity
Mid     North    hvac         Elec       1
        South    hvac         Elec       1
North   Mid      hvac         Elec       1
South   Mid      hvac         Elec       1
```

---

If it's a flat dataframe, use

```
In [168]: df.loc[(df['Site In'] == 'Mid') | (df['Site Out'] == 'Mid')]
Out[168]:
  Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity
0     Mid    North         hvac      Elec
1     Mid    South         hvac      Elec
2   North      Mid         hvac      Elec
4   South      Mid         hvac      Elec
```

Or

```
In [169]: df.loc[df['Site In'].eq('Mid') | df['Site Out'].eq('Mid')]
Out[169]:
  Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity
0     Mid    North         hvac      Elec
1     Mid    South         hvac      Elec
2   North      Mid         hvac      Elec
4   South      Mid         hvac      Elec
```

Comment: (Pdb) m.transmission.loc[(m.transmission['Site In'] == 'Mid') | (m.transmission['Site Out'] == 'Mid')]
*** KeyError: 'Site In'

Comment: I will, but be aware there are some columns I did not add to the question

Comment: I added all the relevant things. Don't get confused with `m.transmission.columns`. Btw I now realized 'Site In' and 'Site Out' are the indices and not columns. Maybe that is the reason it generates a keyerror??

Comment: this works, ty. `m.transmission.loc[(m.transmission.index.get_level_values('Site In') == 'Mid') | (m.transmission.index.get_level_values('Site Out') == 'Mid')]`

Comment: Last question is there a way that I filter `Mid`, without checking the Site in and out? Like search `Mid` in whole dataframe and filter it command?

Comment: For all of multiindex, you can `dff.loc[np.logical_or.reduce([dff.index.get_level_values(x) == 'Mid' for x in dff.index.names])]`

Comment: this looks more promising. The problem is; not all the dataframes indexed by `Site In` or `Site Out`, but `Mid` is always the search value. So better without looking for  `Site In` or `Site Out`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Demo:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]:
                                         val
Site_In Site_Out Transmission Commodity
Mid     North    hvac         Elec         1
        South    hvac         Elec         2
North   Mid      hvac         Elec         3
        South    hvac         Elec         4
South   Mid      hvac         Elec         5
        North    hvac         Elec         6

In [95]: df.query("Site_In == 'Mid' or Site_Out == 'Mid'")
Out[95]:
                                         val
Site_In Site_Out Transmission Commodity
Mid     North    hvac         Elec         1
        South    hvac         Elec         2
North   Mid      hvac         Elec         3
South   Mid      hvac         Elec         5
```

**NOTE:** this approach works only for index/column names that don't contain spaces

Comment: (Pdb) m.transmission[m.transmission.filter(regex=r'^Site').isin(['Mid']).any(1)]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [eff, inv-cost, fix-cost, var-cost, inst-cap, cap-lo, cap-up, wacc, depreciation]
Index: []

Comment: @Icedkk, are `Site In` and `Site Out` - regular columns or multi-index levels?

Comment: @Icedkk, well in this case you've posted an __empty__ sample data set, containing only index values ;) Can you post at least one data column?

Comment: (Pdb) m.transmission.query("Site_In == 'Mid' or Site_Out == 'Mid'")
*** pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'Site_In' is not defined
(Pdb) m.transmission.query("Site In == 'Mid' or Site Out == 'Mid'")
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Saw your edit. You are right with containing spaces issue

Comment: lets make it bold

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. It's very easy to achieve.

```
In [12]: df[(df["Site In"]=="Mid")|(df["Site Out"]=="Mid")]
Out[12]:
  Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity
0     Mid    North         hvac      Elec
1     Mid    South         hvac      Elec
2   North      Mid         hvac      Elec
4   South      Mid         hvac      Elec
```

Comment: You are wrong. m.transmission[(m.transmission["Site In"]=="Mid")|(m.transmission["Site Out"]=="Mid")    ]`*** KeyError: 'Site In'`

Comment: It is because `Site In`and `Site Out` is not columns in this df, but index_levels.

Comment: Sorry I didn't watched that. You can achieve that by using get_level_values() method.